# python pandas quantlib.time.date.Date

Tags: python, pandas, quantlib

I have two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
from quantlib.time.date import Date
cols = ['ColStr','ColDate']
dataset1 = [['A',Date(2017,1,1)],['B',Date(2017,2,2)]]
x = pd.DataFrame(dataset1,columns=cols)
dataset2 = [['A','2017-01-01'],['B','2017-02-04']]
y = pd.DataFrame(dataset2,columns=cols)
```

Now, I want to compare the two table. I have written another set of code that compares the two (larger) dataframes and works for strings and numerical value.

My problem is - with column 'ColDate' one being string type and other being Date type, I am not able to validate if 'ColStr' = A is a match and 'ColStr' = 'B' is a mismatch.

I would have to 
(1) either convert y.ColDate to Date 
(2) or convert x.ColDate to str with a similar format as y.ColDate.

How do I achieve one or the other

Comment: In other words, I want to make 'ColDate' as same data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you need to cast them to a single common type using something like `dataset1['ColDate'] = dataset1.ColDate.map(convert_type)` or any other method to iterate column values. Check other functions from [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) like `apply()`.

The `convert_type` function should be defined in your program and accept a single argument to be passed into `map()`.

And, when the columns have same types, you can compare them using any method you like.

Comment: x['ColDate'] = x.ColDate.map(convert_type).... you meant this. This I think seems to work. I am running my comparison between the two large dataframes, but my tests are passing with this approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [dt.strftime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html#pandas.Series.dt.strftime) function.

`dataset1[0].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`